# Insert into mysql database table date which is in few days week lated from now

Tags: mysql, sql

Following table is used:

```
CREATE TABLE landingList(
isbn varchar(10) NOT NULL,
id varchar(10) NOT NULL,
dateFrom date NOT NULL,
dateTill date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (isbn, id, dateFrom, dateTill),
FOREIGN KEY (isbn) REFERENCES books (isbn),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

Trying to insert following values

```
INSERT INTO library.landingList (isbn, id, dateFrom, dateTill) 
VALUES ('9780596009205','123234 ', NOW(), DATE_ADD(dateFrom, INTERVAL 6 DAY ));
```

for each book INTERVAL will be different value

Comment: In what way does this not work as expected?  Do you get an error?

Comment: You can't just reuse the table to insert new data. Use an `insert ...select`

Answer (score 0):

If your dateFrom is now() you can simply use now() in you DATA_ADD.  see the following:

INSERT INTO library.landingList 
(isbn, id, dateFrom, dateTill) 
VALUES 
('9780596009205','123234 ', **NOW()**, DATE_ADD(**NOW()**, INTERVAL 6 DAY ));

Comment: i can't do that due to constraint, that is a problem :                                                             Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`library`.`landinglist`, CONSTRAINT `landinglist_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`isbn`) REFERENCES `books` (`isbn`))

Comment: Your foreign key constraint problem have to do with using an "isbn" that doesn't exist in your "books" table.  It has nothing to do with the question above and the usage of now() in date_add().  BTW the isbn you use in your insert is bigger than 10 characters, maybe that has to to with your problem, if your mysql instance is not set to catch those kinds of error.